# Webpack, insert/add new CSS to the bundle?

Tags: javascript, webpack, font-awesome-5

I have a third-party function which returns CSS as a `string`. I need this CSS in my webpack bundle.

I've created a new plugin:

```
import fontawesome from '@fortawesome/fontawesome'
import { RawSource } from 'webpack-sources'

class FontAwesome {
  apply (compiler) {
    compiler.plugin('compilation', (compilation) => {
      compilation.plugin('additional-assets', (callback) => {
        compilation.assets['css/fontawesome.css'] = new RawSource(fontawesome.dom.css())
        callback()
      })
    })
  }
}

export default FontAwesome
```

This spits out a new asset called `fontawesome.css` containing the CSS. I could just link this file in alongside my main bundle, but I'd rather have all the CSS in one file.

How might I insert new CSS into the bundle that I'm already creating (which uses `extract-text-webpack-plugin`)...?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?